# How to implement Singleton Pattern (syntax)

Tags: f#, singleton

I have a cache of data which is getting refreshed from an outside source, and I want to limit my access tot his cache (readonly) inside of my app.  I don't want to have refresh the datasource everytime I need access to it (ie. on instantiation go and pull all the data I need, as there is quite a bit of data that is being kept up to date).

```
type MySingleton = 

        [<DefaultValue>]
        static val mutable private instance: MySingleton

        static member GetInstance() = 
            instance
```

I guess this is one of the gotchas about implementing a project and trying to learn the language at the same time.  I know the logic needs to be

```
if instance is null
    synchronize
    if instance is null
        instance = new MySingleton()
```

but the lack of null is throwing me for a loop.  I think I can use an option type etc but it is throwing me for a loop

```
type MySingleton = 

        [<DefaultValue>]
        static val mutable private instance: MySingleton option

        static member GetInstance() = 
            match instance with
                 | Some(i) -> i
                 | None -> 
                            *MySingleton.instance = new MySingleton()
                            MySingleton.instance*
```

that logic is wrong according to the compiler...

```
       if Helper.notExists MySingleton.instance then
            MySingleton.instance <- Some(new MySingleton())        
       MySingleton.instance
```

should I be using IF statements instead?  Is there a prefered pattern for this syntax in f#?

Comment: serious comment this time. Just to make sure you are asking for help on the right thing, a singleton is a special crafted class that you can try to create as many instance as you want, but after the first one, each time you just get given that first instance. so if you tried to create an array of singletons, you just get an array of that same object. From reading your question, its hard to tell if you really want this behaviour.

Comment: Yes I do; The singleton will contain a large cache of data, and provide access to the data whenever needed without each usage of the class needing to refresh/fetch the data (which is a long process).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Lazy` type as Brian mentioned is a good place to start with. It allows you to ensure that a computation will be run when the value is needed and it guarantees thread safety, meaning that the computation will run only once (although, in some cases, you may also use [`PublicationOnly` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx) to specify that multiple threads may start to initialize cache and only the first result will be used).

However, you'll probably also need a mechanism for marking the cache as invalid (e.g. after some specified time) and forcing re-initialization of the cache. Note that this isn't really a *Singleton pattern*. Anyway, you can still do this in a thread safe way using `Lazy`, but you'll need to structure the code like this:

```
module Cache = 
  // returns a lazy value that initializes the cache when 
  // accessed for the first time (safely)
  let private createCacheInitialization() = 
    lazy( // some code to calculate cache 
          cache )
  // current cache represented as lazy value
  let mutable private currentCache = createCacheInitialization()

  // Returns the current cache
  let GetCache() = currentCache.Value
  // Reset - cache will be re-initialized next time it is accessed
  // (this doesn't actually initialize a cache - just creates a lazy value)
  let Reset() = currentCache <- createCacheInitialization()
```

Of course, you could turn this code into a `Cache` class that takes only the initialization function and encapsulates the rest of the code into a reusable piece (if you need to cache multiple values, for example).

Answer (score 16):

Both .NET 4.0 and F# have `Lazy`, so I think you want

```
module MySingleton =
    let private x = Lazy.Create(fun() -> 42)
    let GetInstance() = x.Value
```

(where `42` might be a `new WhateverType()` or whatever the expensive initialization is).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx

(Commentary: It's 2010, and getting rare to have to explicitly deal with synchronization primitives; languages and libraries are encapsulating all the common patterns.)

Comment: Is there a difference between `Lazy.Create(fun() -> 42)` and `lazy( 42 )` or are those just different syntax for the same thing? If `42` were a constructor call, would it be delayed in both versions?

Comment: Same thing; lazy(expr) means Lazy.Create(fun()->expr)

Comment: @Brian--isn't basic F# development basically a singleton?  I mean seriously--you assign one time and then read from that value over and over again.  I'm not sure I understand the difference between this and the singleton pattern.

Comment: @Onorio: The singleton pattern is about two things; having everyone get the same reference to a named object (which is kinda like what you are saying), and avoiding bad side-effects from initialization code (where effects may be actual side-effects, or just 'perf' effects, e.g. something that is slow, or takes up a lot of memory or other resources).  You want to ensure that these effects never happen more than once (you only need one object), and that they don't happen unless needed (if no one uses the object, no effects).  The lazy initialization buys those effects-guarantees.

Comment: @Brian--ok, I believe I understand what you're saying.

Comment: I ownder how the lazy.create works when interoped with c# - I will need to test that piece out

Answer (score 11):

Sorry to reanimate an old question, just wanted to point out that some might try to expose `Instance` in a public property, in which case the following piece of code might be useful:

```
// private constructor, just as any OO singleton
type public MyType private() =
  inherit SomeParent()

  static let mutable instance = lazy(new MyType())

  // Get the instance of the type
  static member Instance with get() = instance.Value
```

Comment: And, the singleton pattern should have a private constructor, so: `type public MyType private () =`

Answer (score 8):

The question was *how to implement the Singleton pattern*, not *how to implement the Lazy-Load pattern*. A singleton can be implemented thread-safely in several ways, e.g.:

```
// Standard approach in F# 2.0: using an implicit constructor.
type Singleton private() =
    static let instance = new Singleton()
    static member Instance = instance

// Abbreviated approach in F# 3.0: using an implicit constructor with auto property.
type Singleton private() =
    static member val Instance = Singleton()

// Alternative example: When you have to use an explicit ctor,
// and also want to check instanciation upon each access of the property.

/// This type is intended for private use within Singleton only.
type private SyncRoot = class end

type Singleton =
    [<DefaultValue>]
    static val mutable private instance: Singleton

    private new() = { }

    static member Instance = 
        lock typeof<SyncRoot> (fun() ->
            if box Singleton.instance = null then
                Singleton.instance <- Singleton())
        Singleton.instance
```

**Edit**
Added a simplified F# 2.0 example with private implicit ctor, and the example with explicit ctor now uses a separate private type as sync root. Thanks to kvb for the hints.

**Edit 2**
Added F# 3.0 auto property syntax.

Comment: 1.  You can make a default constructor private (as in, `type PersonSingleton private() = ...`), in which case you can use `static let` within the type.  2.  Don't lock on a type instance; because the type is public other code could also lock on it, causing a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for never deleting this answer. The private access modifier for an implicit constructor was exactly the piece I was missing!

Comment: What's the reason you box the Singleton.instance here?

Comment: @Snake reference types defined in F# are, by default, not nullable. To compare the Singleton with null, we have to upcast to System.Object, which is a non-F#-defined CLI type who is allowed to be `null`. Another solution would be `if System.Object.ReferenceEquals(Singleton.instance, null) ...`