# Error implementing Singleton pattern (within mutually recursive types)

Tags: f#, singleton, lazy-evaluation

I'm attempting to implement the singleton pattern, but receiving an error. My implementation looks functionally identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691565/f-how-to-implement-singleton-pattern-syntax/2691731#2691731) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691565/f-how-to-implement-singleton-pattern-syntax/3959413#3959413). I'm using a class instead of a module because it implements an interface.

```
type SystemObjectFactory private () =
    static let instance = lazy ( SystemObjectFactory() )
    static member Instance = instance.Value //ERROR
```

The exception is:

> > System.InvalidOperationException: The static initialization of a file or type resulted in static data being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized.

How can I correct this?

As a side note, I'm not sure why the following (which I prefer) doesn't work either:

```
type SystemObjectFactory private () =
    static let instance = SystemObjectFactory()
    static member Instance = instance
```

**UPDATE**

I may have discovered the problem. This class is being referred to from the static constructor of a mutually recursive type. Apparently, this is dark and forbidden magic in .NET.

More context:

```
type Entity() =
    static do
        Bootstrapper(SystemObjectFactory.Instance).Init() //PURE EVIL

and SystemObjectFactory private () =
    static let instance = SystemObjectFactory()
    static member Instance = instance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what way does your prefered version not work?  When I type it into FSI it seems to work:

```
> type SystemObjectFactory private () =
    static let instance = SystemObjectFactory()
    static member Instance = instance;;

type SystemObjectFactory =
  class
    private new : unit -> SystemObjectFactory
    static member Instance : SystemObjectFactory
  end

> SystemObjectFactory.Instance;;
val it : SystemObjectFactory = FSI_0002+SystemObjectFactory
```

**Update**

Try switching the order of your recursive types!

```
type SystemObjectFactory private () =
    static let instance = SystemObjectFactory()
    static member Instance = instance
and Entity() =
    static do
        SystemObjectFactory.Instance = SystemObjectFactory.Instance |> ignore //slightly evil
```

Comment: I updated the question. I needed to provide more context...and I think I've found the problem. Now, to figure out how best to refactor...

Comment: Ha! That did it. Now it's only slightly evil. Thanks.