# Implementing ThreadStatic singleton in F#

Tags: f#, singleton

I'm learning F# and would like to implement ThreadStatic singleton. I'm using what I found in a similar question: [F# How to implement Singleton Pattern (syntax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691565/f-how-to-implement-singleton-pattern-syntax)

With the following code compiler complains that `The type 'MySingleton' does not have 'null' as a proper value`.

```
type MySingleton = 
    private new () = {}
    [<ThreadStatic>] [<DefaultValue>] static val mutable private instance:MySingleton
    static member Instance =
        match MySingleton.instance with
        | null -> MySingleton.instance <- new MySingleton()
        | _ -> ()
        MySingleton.instance
```

How could I initialize the instance in this scenario?

Comment: FYI you can combine multiple attributes like: `[<System.ThreadStatic; DefaultValue>]`

Comment: One other piece of advice -- [<ThreadStatic>] is fine to learn with, but don't use it in production if you care about performance. There are other ways to implement a thread-keyed multiton which are much faster than [<ThreadStatic>], albeit requiring more code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think `[<ThreadStatic>]` leads to rather clunky code, especially in F#. There are ways to do this more concisely, for example, using [`ThreadLocal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx):

```ml
open System.Threading

type MySingleton private () = 
  static let instance = new ThreadLocal<_>(fun () -> MySingleton())
  static member Instance = instance.Value
```

Answer (score 4):

Another F#y solution would be to store instance as an [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx)

```
type MySingleton = 
    private new () = {}

    [<ThreadStatic>; <DefaultValue>]
    static val mutable private instance:Option<MySingleton>

    static member Instance =
        match MySingleton.instance with
        | None -> MySingleton.instance <- Some(new MySingleton())
        | _ -> ()

        MySingleton.instance.Value
```

Answer (score 3):

Close to what Ramon said, apply the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute to the type (by default types declared in F# do not allow 'null' as a proper value):

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type MySingleton = 
    private new () = {}
    [<ThreadStatic>] [<DefaultValue>] static val mutable private instance:MySingleton
    static member Instance =
        match MySingleton.instance with
        | null -> MySingleton.instance <- new MySingleton()
        | _ -> ()
        MySingleton.instance
```