# Why the box here?

Tags: f#, boxing

While browsing StackOverflow I stumbled upon the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817367/162694

```
// ... removed unneeded code
/// This type is intended for private use within Singleton only.
type private SyncRoot = class end

type Singleton =
    [<DefaultValue>]
    static val mutable private instance: Singleton

    private new() = { }

    static member Instance = 
        lock typeof<SyncRoot> (fun() ->
            // vvv
            if box Singleton.instance = null then
            // ^^^
                Singleton.instance <- Singleton())
        Singleton.instance
```

Can somebody elaborate why the `box` here is needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given `Singleton` type doesn't have `null` as a proper value. In other words, it's not nullable and normally shouldn't have the value `null`. Hence, it is not sensible to compare a value of type `Singleton` with `null`, even though the use of an uninitialized variable via `[<DefaultValue>]` may create a null-valued variable of this type. Boxing turns anything into `obj`, which is nullable and therefore valid in this context.

Using `Unchecked.defaultof<Singleton>` instead of `null` would make the boxing unnecessary and compile. (There's also the `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` attribute, which can be added to the `Singleton` type to specify that instances of this type can be `null`.)